# Debugging a simple haskell function to place colors to nodes "graphColor"

Tags: debugging, haskell

So I have an assignment in haskell that I am stuck on with my logic and this is the problem I was given:

graphColor finds all possible colorings for a graph
  a coloring is an assignment of nodes to colors
    such that two nodes must have different colors if they are connected by an
edge

graphColor takes the following arguments

1. A list of colors
2. A list of nodes
3. A list of edges (i.e., pairs of nodes)
4. A partial coloring (i.e., a list of pairs of node and color)

Example list of edges

```
e1 :: [Edge]
e1 = [(1,3),(2,1),(2,5),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(5,6),(2,6)]

e2 :: [Edge]
e2 = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,3),(2,4),(1,4)]

type Code = [(Char,Char)]

-- domain of our code

domain1 :: [Char]
domain1 = ['a'..'z']

-- associated range

range1 :: [Char]
range1 = ['q'..'z'] ++ ['a'..'p']

-- create a code out of our domain and range
code1 :: Code
code1 = zip domain1 range1
```

`graphColor` returns all complete colorings of the graph, if there is more than one solution, your list does not need to contain all of them, as long as it contains at least one.

### Ex1:

```
> take 1 (graphColor "abc" [1..6] e1 [])
[[(6,'c'),(5,'a'),(4,'a'),(3,'c'),(2,'b'),(1,'a')]]
```

### Ex2:

```
> take 1 (graphColor "abc" [1..4] e2 [])
[]
```

This is my code thus far which just returns the empty list no matter what.

```
graphColor :: [Color] -> [Node] -> [Edge] -> Coloring -> [Coloring]
-- Fill in your code here
graphColor colors nodes edges solution
  | length nodes == length solution = [solution]
  | otherwise = concat [graphColor colors nodes edges (newSol : solution) |
                             x <- nodes, y <- colors,
                             newSol <- [(x,y)],
                             notRepeat solution edges x y,
                             notElem newSol solution]
notRepeat :: Coloring -> [Edge] -> Node -> Color -> Bool
notRepeat solution edges x y 
  | x `elem` [z | (z,_) <- solution] = False
  |otherwise = helpHelper edges [z | (z,y) <- solution] x

helpHelper edges matchedNodes x
   = x `elem` [z | y <- matchedNodes, (z,y) <- edges] ++
     [z | y <- matchedNodes, (y,z) <- edges]
```